# pyhf: POI application using formula

Tags: pyhf

I am trying to write a likelihood model in which the POI affects two samples, but while one I have the regular POI*yield, the other I have f(POI)*yield where f is an arbitrary function.

Is there a simple way to implement that in pyhf?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyhf currently does not support it, but it's something that is on our mind. Can you open an issue on our github with this as a feature request and we can work out how to do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just did it: https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/issues/850