# Nuisance parameters which are related between channels

Tags: pyhf

I want to do a combined fit, where the normalization of a background is related between two channels (regions in my case) using an ABCD formula. I've been using a standard `normfactor` so far to vary the normalization in a correlated way, but that also means that the absolute parameter value is the same.

Is there a possibility to define two parameters related by a formula (effectively a scale parameter in my case)?

(I suppose this is more or less the same as [pyhf: POI application using formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543239/pyhf-poi-application-using-formula) and corresponding issue)

Comment: Depending on your use case, if you need a generic formula - then indeed this is not currently supported as in the issue you linked. If, however, you want a correlated impact with different normalizations, the same across all bins of a given sample, then a [normsys](https://scikit-hep.org/pyhf/likelihood.html#normalisation-uncertainty-normsys) should work for you.

Comment: Ah, so you mean I could maybe emulate a factor between two parameters by effectively mapping a fully correlated parameter [-1,1] to different actual normalization ranges in different samples?

Comment: Exactly. That's a way to do it with normsys.